# styleUrls ionic - 404 (Not Found)

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

Does anyone know how to solve the 404 file not found for a .scss on a component :

[image]

this is my .ts file

I would assume this is how you connect your styling
the .scss and the .ts is in the same calendar/ directory

```
@Component({
  selector: 'calendar',
  styleUrls: **['calendar.component.scss']**,
  templateUrl: 'calendar.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Has anyone else stumbled upon this issue.
I have tried :

styleUrls: ['calendar.component.scss'],
 styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss'],
also :

in the app.scss, like so :

```
@import '../components/calendar/calendar'
@import '../components/calendar/calendar/calender.component.scss'
```

all attempts are unsuccessful. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of Ionic? Normally you don't have to specify the link to the scss file if it is in same folder with same name.
I would remove all link references and check if it is matching in terms of name / selector.'

Comment: Actually removing the link kinda works for me. Thanks @Aug

Comment: @Sampgun I'm glad if I could help.

Comment: Isn't there a way to compile the SCSSs in Angular way? I have to import an Angular 5 app in Ionic and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

## Ionic 4:

Seems the actual `styleUrls` is a little bugged for relative paths.
Change `styleUrls` with `styles` for example:

`styles: ['favourites.scss']`,